# Accessing Remote Desktop through VPN on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, routing, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

We have 2 networks at my current workplace - an administrative network everyone uses and a "lab" network which only engineers, scientists, and developers use.  I have control over all servers and PCs on the lab network using Active Directory.  Due to the pandemic, we are all working from home.  The administrative side has issued us with one IP mapped to one of my lab Windows 2012 r2 servers.  Using my administrative laptop connected to the VPN (Pulse Secure), I (and other lab network users) can map shares from that lab server. I discovered I can also access it through Remote Desktop.  I would like to know if it's possible to setup a routing service on that server to allow others to remote into their own desktop PCs, using this server's assigned VPN IP.  For example, if the assigned VPN IP is 1.1.1.1 and the actual lab server IP is 2.2.2.2, could a user enter 1.1.1.1/mypc to get to their PC named "mypc"?

I've looked at the server roles such as Remote Desktop Services, but I believe that just allows users to have desktop sessions from a VM or a session on the server.  I want them to be able to log into their own physical PC via RD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your can accomplish it by  two ways

Scenario 1 ; make changes in your network deploy vpn devices and connect it with your network core layer3 switch and frame policies in vpn device allowing destination as pc ips and Souce as vpn pool DHCP allocated pool..Enable routing
In vpn device assuming your PC's lan pool : 172.16.10.0/24

In vpn device

Ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 pointing towards gateway of coreswitch
Ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 pointing towards gateway of isp

Scenario 2 : create termination server create multiple vm instances as same as vdi setup . Uses can access terminal server from termination server users can RDP to pc or desktops on administrator zone